# How to create a budget with enabling notification channel by using Cloud Billing Budget API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

Able to create budgets by leveraging Cloud Billing Budget API but couldn't able to add / enable notification channels for the budget to get an alert .

Please advise .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default functionality is to send alerts on budget threshold to users with the Billing Account Administrator or Billing Account User role. The console UI allows you to also map Monitoring notification channels, that enables the functionality of customizing the email addresses where threshold alerts get sent. I am not aware of any way to do this through the API.

You can create ThresholdRules through the API, that then send automatic emails to Billing Account Admins and Users (as per the default behaviour). This does not help you if you need a custom email or some other channel to send the notification.

The other thing you can do is configure your own pub/sub topic to receive all updates related to budgets. You can then map a function to programmatically to the pub/sub topic to do something on updates. This is documented at https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets-programmatic-notifications

You can also take a look at https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/budget/rpc/google.cloud.billing.budgets.v1beta1#google.cloud.billing.budgets.v1beta1.AllUpdatesRule.

Comment: I think you can: Use the Cloud Billing Budget API to:

    Create a separate budget for each of your Google Cloud projects so you know which areas of your Google Cloud environment are spending more than expected.
    Bulk update all of your budgets after quarterly financial planning.
    Integrate with your company's deployment manager to add the creation of budgets to your cloud provisioning workflow.

Comment: link: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budget-api-overview

Comment: How does any of this help with mapping notification channels to budget thresholdrules through the API?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budget-api

Comment: ?? The original question is about creating notification channels connected to budgets, not about creating budgets.

Comment: I beg to differ it says creating budget with notification!

Comment: I think you have trouble with reading comprehension. He specifically mentions notification channels. This is something you can do on the console UI, go take a look. Now show me an API that you can create a budget with a notification channel connected to it.

Comment: I think you may have the same problem!

Comment: Yes Ville , No options to add notification channels apart from default one (billing admin) though API . Thanks for the answer